# How to limit array values in implode output

Tags: php, arrays

I have more than 10 values in my array.

I would like to separate it with comma.

So I used this code

```
echo implode(",", $array);
```

Can someone tell me how to limit the values.? I need only the first three values

Comment: [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array-slice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

slice the array first

```
$newArray = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
echo implode(',', $newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_slice` :

```
 $slicedArray = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
 $input=implode(",", $slicedArray);
```

Comment: The `array_slice` needs to be first